# How to get TPS/QPS metrics with postgres_exporter in AWS Aurora PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, prometheus

We want to get TPS/QPS metrics of Aurora PostgreSQL in AWS RDS with [postgres_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter).

Here are the metrics we try to use

- TPS metric

```
irate(pg_stat_database_xact_commit[2m])
```

- QPS metric

```
irate(pg_stat_database_tup_fetched[2m])
```

Could someone help us to double check whether the above metrics correct or not?